# Error opening nib in xcode: Error updating Objective-C type information. Multiple types...registered with the same Objective-C name: AppDelegate

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Just getting started with xamarin studio and iOS development...  I'm trying to set up my development projects. When setting all this up, I had initially created a project called 'MyProject.iOS'.  I later decided that I didn't want the 'p' in MyProject to be capitalized.  I deleted the existing project (using finder), removed it from my existing solution, and created a new one named 'Myproject.iOS'.

Now, when I try to open the Myproject_iOSViewController.xib file to edit in xCode, I get the following error:

Error updating Objective-C type information. Multiple types (MyProject.iOS.AppDelegate and Myproject.iOS.AppDelegate) registered with the same Objective-C name: AppDelegate

Seems like something is stuck in xCode from my original project that had the same name w/ different casing.  I looked in Finder and confirmed that all the old files are gone.

I believe I am experiencing the same issue that was reported here (not sure why this issue is marked as resolved):  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7550

The last commenter has a great repo and reports this solution that worked for him:
 1. Close XS
 2. Delete ~/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-4.0 folder
 3. Open XS : voilà everything works again now !

My issue at this point is that I cannot find the ~/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-4.0 to delete.  I found a ~Library/Caches/ folder but it did not have a XamarinStudio-4.0 sub-folder in there.  How can I resolve this?

I am using 4.0.9 (Build 12) of Xamarin studio.

Here is the full stack trace from the error message box that shows up when I double click the xib file:
System.ArgumentException: Multiple types (MyProject.iOS.AppDelegate and Myproject.iOS.AppDelegate) registered with the same Objective-C name: AppDelegate
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectProjectInfo.Update () [0x00118] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-4.0.9-branch/f9c5c24e/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectProjectInfo.cs:98 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectProjectInfo.Update (Boolean force) [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-4.0.9-branch/f9c5c24e/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectProjectInfo.cs:72 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.UpdateTypes (IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x0003c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-4.0.9-branch/f9c5c24e/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeProjectTracker.cs:476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this problem. I used that post to solve it. At first I could not find the folder that is referenced. This is how I found it.

1. Go into finder on the Mac.
2. Under Favorites on the left of the screen, select the primary volume. For me that was labeled Macintosh HD.
3. Select Go/Go to Folder from the toolbar.
4. In the Go to the Folder screen that pops up type in ~/Library.
5. From there you can navigate to the proper directory and delete it.

Hope that helps. Best of luck.